# Add Padding to Default Flutter App

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm learning Flutter, and I've made some VERY simple modifications to the starter app, so that the floating button changes the text item to a random string from an array.

The problem is that the text is too close to the edge of the screen--needs padding. But whenever I try to add a `padding:` element in any number of places, VSCode doesn't seem to like it. I've seen padding used in other example code, but can't seem to get it to work in this case.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text(widget.title),
    ),
    body: new Center(
      child: new Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text(
            'Welcome to DadBot!',
          ),
          new Text(
            _txt,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: _changeText,
      tooltip: 'Increment',
      child: new Icon(Icons.add),
    ),
  );
}
```

[image: Text without padding.]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get padding is to wrap your widget in a [`Padding`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Padding-class.html) widget and specify the offset you want.

Comment: Also if you're struggling with stuff like this, I'd recommend reading through and following some of the tutorials from the flutter website; it'll save you time. The [Layout one](https://flutter.io/tutorials/layout/) in particular is relevant to this question, although it doesn't mention the Padding widget directly and uses Containers instead (which are another option).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by wrapping the Text widget in question within a Padding class, like so:

```
new Padding(
  padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
  child: new Text(
    _txt,
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
  ),
),
```

I'm still getting used to the way Flutter does things, but I like it!